# Unable to access dict values indjango view

Tags: python, arrays, loops, object, dictionary

I want to save an array of objects passed from javascript through ajax to me database. This is my view code:

```
data2 = json.loads(request.raw_get_data)
    for i in data2:
        print(key)
        obj = ShoppingCart(quantity = i.quantity , user_id = 3, datetime = datetime.now(), product_id = i.pk)
        obj.save()

    return render_to_response("HTML.html",RequestContext(request))
```

After the first line, i get this in my dictionary: 
`[{'model': 'Phase_2.product', 'fields': {'name': 'Bata', 'category': 2, 'quantity': 1, 'subcategory': 1, 'count': 2, 'price': 50}, 'imageSource': None, 'pk': 1}]`

(Only one object in the array right now)

I want to be able access individual fields like quantity, id, etc in order to save the data to my database. When i debug this code, it gives a name error on 'i'. I also tried accessing the fields like this: `data2[0].quantity` but it gives this error: `{AttributeError}dict object has no attribute quantity`.

Edited code:

```
for i in data2:
        name = i["fields"]["name"]
        obj = ShoppingCart(quantity = i["fields"]["quantity"] , user_id = 3, datetime = datetime.now(), product_id = i["fields"]["pk"])
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help you to visualise the returned dict with proper formatting:

```
[
    {
     'model': 'Phase_2.product',
     'fields': {
                'name': 'Bata',
                'category': 2, 
                'quantity': 1, 
                'subcategory': 1, 
                'count': 2, 
                'price': 50
               },
     'imageSource': None,
     'pk': 1
    }
]
```

The most likely reason for your error is that you are trying to access values of of the inner `'fields'` dictionary as if they belong to the outer `i` dictionary.

i.e.

```
# Incorrect
i["quantity"]
# Gives KeyError

# Correct
i["fields"]["quantity"]
```

**Edit**

You have the same problem in your update:

```
# Incorrect
i["fields"]["pk"]

# Correct
i["pk"]
```

The `"pk"` field is in the outer dictionary, not the inner `"fields"` dictionary.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one more question. When i access i['fields']['quantity'] in the "for i in data2", i still get the same error. But when i do this : data2[0]['fields']['quantity'], it gives the correct value. Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The issue is the same as the original one. You are accessing "pk" incorrectly this time.

Comment: No but it should give me the correct value when i do this "i["fields"]["name"], no? It gives an error on this.

Comment: I did change that to i['pk']. It is still giving me the same error.

Comment: You have either incorrectly copied the format of the dictionary, have made a typo somewhere or have a case of two variables named `i`. I have no problems accessing the dict you posted via the method you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
i['fields']['quantity']
```

The json.loads() returns you a dictionary, which should be accessed by key.